# Access 2 records at the same time?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know if there is a way to access 2 rows of a model table in my view for Edit. As I would like to edit one of the record only in the view, I cannot load a list that contains the 2 methods at the GET edit controller method. Is there any way that allows my to query for the next record inside my view?

My controller methods

```
 // GET: Record/Edit/5
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
            if (record == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(record);
        }

        // POST: Record/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RecordID,BeforeDate,AfterDate,ShiftIDBefore,ShiftIDAfter,EmpAID,EmpBID,Reason,Self_interchange,Status")] Record record, string button)
        { 
//Codes for modifying the record
}
```

My view

```
@model Interchangesys.Models.Record


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Process interchange record</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RecordID)
        <dt>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Accept" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width:200px;height:50px;font-size: 25px;" />
                    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Reject" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width:200px;height:50px;font-size: 25px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </dt>
<!--rest of the codes that shows the content of record with the same id and content of record with the id +1-->
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use Tag notation in Title. That's why you have tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand you correctly, you just want to show info about two records in your view.

You could pass the the next record to be available in your View via ViewBag like this:

```
Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
Record next = db.Records.Find(id + 1);

ViewBag.Next = next;
return(record);
```

And then in your view you access it like:

```
@{
    Record next = (Record)ViewBag.Next;
}
```

And finally, to use it in a view, you would do something like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("NextRecordID", next.RecordID) // You can't use @Html.HiddenFor
```

Alternatively, you could pass both records via ViewBag, like this:

```
Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
Record next = db.Records.Find(id + 1);

ViewBag.Record = record  
ViewBag.Next = next;
return(); // There will be no model for your view.
```

And then prefix the fields in the view like this:

```
@{
    Record record = (Record)ViewBag.Record;
    Record next = (Record)ViewBag.Next;
}

@Html.Hidden("record.RecordID", record.RecordID)
@Html.Hidden("next.RecordID", next.RecordID)
```

So you get them both in your Edit function like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "record", Include = "...")] Record record, [Bind(Prefix = "next", Include = "...")] Record next, string button)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thank you! The application is based on the dafault template, so I had to specify the full class name in the view. i.e. Interchangesys.Models.Record next = (Interchangesys.Models.Record)ViewBag.Next; to access it.